# ReactJS Code Splitting causes an error when loading Bootstrap through WebPack into Wordpress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, webpack, lazy-loading

I am currently using a WebPack configuration that allows for the direct injection of ReactJS into a site. This compiles all of the React code into a single index.js, and I am trying to code split it because the file is getting very large. Without the code split, bootstrap is not loaded, because I have it as part of my WordPress theme. When I use React.lazy() though, I get 404 errors for 0.js which my developer tools say is caused by bootstrap. Here is my index.js:

```
const Register = lazy(() => import('./components/register/register')); // Import function
```

and for the rendering:

```
<Suspense fallback={<div><Loader/></div>}><div id="container"><Register /></div></Suspense>
```

With the module imported normally like `import Register from './components/register/register';` it works perfectly fine, but as soon as I use lazy, the console begins throwing errors. WebPack compiles correctly either way. Here is a screenshot of the console error:

[image: Console error]

[image: Another console error]

Any help would be appreciated because I usually use Create-React-App and don't know much about customizing WebPack. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked very hard to figure out what the root of the issue was, and it turned out that the browser was looking for the 0.js chunk on the https://example.com/register/0.js when the file was in fact sitting at https://example.com/wp-content/themes/theme/build/0.js. A few google searches and some trial and error later I figured out a WebPack config that would allow for this to compile correctly. It is as follows:

```
output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        publicPath: '/wp-content/themes/theme/build/'
    },
```

Just documenting this in case someone else has the same issue.